# rails route to specific script

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create route `/branch` which run script `/lib/branch.rb`, I need to display only one string which displayed in browser my current git branch which deployed at staging server. I already write script, but cant understand how to mount it to rails routes

Comment: can you show us the script? is it a class or a module? a method?
The basic way to do it would be to call that functionality from a controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails routes dispatch requests to the application. You can put your code in either a Controller or a Rack app (Rails 3 only).

If you are using Rails 3, you can use the Rack API to do it right inside your `routes.rb`.

`match "/branch" => proc { |env| [ 200, {}, [ %{your script call} ] ] }`

Take a look at this post: http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/rails-routing

Answer (score 1):

Rails routes are routing the request to controllers.

So put your code in /app/controllers/branch-controller.rb